# What's Beck's ultimate plan?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

After seeing Spider Man Far From Home I'm still kind of confused as to what the villain's plan and motivation were. So basically what I understand so far is

> Beck wants to convince the world that he is just as good as the Avengers because he hates Tony Stark. He used the projectors to record a video of Spider Man murdering him and attacking the city, which also reveals his secret identity, and released it before he died as a form of getting revenge on Spider Man.

But what exactly is the goal, is he trying to conquer the world? Or just trick people for no good reason? What does Stark even have to do with it, other than the fact that he

> fired them all?

What was the **end goal** to his plan, and his motivation exactly?

Comment: I don't think there was very much to it other than he wanted to become the new version of The Avengers so he could have the fame and recognition.

Comment: 1. Hallucinatory drone projections. 2. Appear to defeat said projections, thus gaining the trust of the remnants of SHIELD. 3. Obtain access to Stark's larger network of drones. 4. ??? 5. Profit!

Comment: What I want to know is, if he was gunning to become the next "big superhero" by fighting fake threats...what's the plan when a real threat comes along?

Comment: This is setting up the stage for Sinister Six and Marvel Phase 4

Comment: Zip Zap, I think the plan was that once they had EDITH they would have the fire power to fight any real threat to come along. As it was, even without it they were able to fend off Spider-man for a while. Mysterio probably figured that with the ability to level places like London, he'd be able to take on whatever came along.

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles if you use an at-sign before someone's name it will automatically notify them of your response :)

Comment: Crap - totally rough morning for me, I wasn't even thinking. @Dj-spicy-deluxe-levi

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles Looking at your profile I see you've been here a while, I just assumed you where a new user when I saw that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Beck's plan was shared by his acolytes (henceforth referred as the "Mysterio gang"). The Mysterio gang was only comprised of **former humiliated / dejected Stark Industries** employees. Their main point of contention is that Tony Stark is remembered as a saint for his sacrifice as Iron Man against Thanos (getting whole street paintings, etc.), even though he built (from their point of view) his whole super-heroic career on his employees' back (demonstrably false) and treated them as punchlines to his own jokes (which, yes, was 100% asshole-ish). There's also a few of them who were fired when Stark Industries flipped from weapon-makers to... whatever they do next.

Their **main goal**, achieved at the middle of the movie, is **to coerce / manipulate Peter into giving up EDITH**, who is the key to Tony Stark's kingdom. Their con was extremely long-winded, but as they note themselves, they had to fool Nick Fury himself (who was actually Talos, but Beck didn't know that) to ensure everything went fine in the long run.

**By getting EDITH, the Mysterio gang finally gains back control on their own inventions and creations.** However, Beck has a grander plan : entirely replacing Iron Man in popular culture and the public's mind-space. By fighting off supposedly tangible, spectacular threats all around the globe, Mysterio would have appeared as a "new Avenger" type of hero. An international saint saving lives better than Iron Man ever could, with even better publicity. **I guess the Mysterio gang also wanted to reap the rewards from world-class popularity.**

__

Less factually, I also believe Quentin Beck specifically wanted to persuade Peter Parker into giving up his super-hero career. Beck sees Peter as a fake messiah, a strawman chosen by Stark to inherit his wealth and resources even though they had no former bond, nothing. When receiving EDITH, Beck says :

> Quentin Beck: [to Peter] You’re right, you may not be ready, but this is my responsibility.

https://www.moviequotesandmore.com/spider-man-far-from-home-new-quotes/

Beck believes Peter doesn't have the shoulders or legitimacy to continue Iron Man's legacy. He is persuaded he is the only one worthy of incarnating the next "big" superhero. As he says himself right before the final battle : "Who knows ? Perhaps I'm gonna be shaking the Queen's hand in 5 minutes" (paraphrased).

**TL;DR** While the Mysterio gang mainly wanted to wrench Stark Enterprises' resources away from Peter and reap the fruits of their own labor (with some large extras), Quentin Beck also had a gigantic ego complex and wished for Iron Man-levels of popularity.